# How can I align the Social Icons horizontally

Tags: css

I am trying to align the icons under the Share This Course icon horizontally, it works in the sidebar but not my content. Any advice?

Example here

http://www.themarketinggroup.ca/canscribe/courses/medical-transcription-healthcare-documentation-course/

Comment: we require piece of code to understand your problem and than can possibly help you to solve it!

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? Is it that the default behavior of the icons is to wrap vertically?

Answer (score 1):

The icons in the sidebar are floated to the left.

One solution would be to add a rule of float: left to the .widget li selector, like so:

```
.widget li { float: left; }
```

You could then add the desired amount of spacing between each icon with padding or margin rules.

You could also use [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp). What you would do in that case is make the ul with a class of socials display: flex and add the additional rule of justify-content to give the icons some horizontal spacing. Something like this:

```
ul.socials { display: flex; justify-content: space-around; }
```

I like the latter solution because it takes care of spacing the icons for you.

Answer (score 0):

The possible ways to achieve this one is by using    **float**

```
    .display_inline li  {
                 float: left; // inline elements in left             
                 margin: 10px;  //to create some space between the icons

                   }
```